# c# return concatenation of properties

Tags: c#

I have a class:

```
public class LabOccurrenceForm
{          
    public DateTime Occurrence_Date { get; set; }
    public string Cup_Type { get; set; }
    public string Analytical_Testing_Phase { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Preanalytical_Before_Testing { get; set; }
    public string Postanalytical_After_Testing { get; set; }
    public string Other { get; set; }
    public string Practice_Code { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to add a method in the class that will concatenate all the variables like this:

```
public string AllData
{
    return Occurrence_Date.ToString() + " " +
    Cup_Type + " " +
    Analytical_Testing_Phase + " " +
    Area + " " +
    Preanalytical_Before_Testing + " " +
    Postanalytical_After_Testing + " " +
    Other + " " +
    Practice_Code + " " +
    Comments;
}
```

This did not work because it wants a get or set. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Error 3 A get or set accessor expected it wont build

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, make it a property and give it a [`get`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228503.aspx)...

```
public string AllData
{
    get
    {
        return Occurrence_Date.ToString() + " " +
        Cup_Type + " " +
        Analytical_Testing_Phase + " " +
        Area + " " +
        Preanalytical_Before_Testing + " " +
        Postanalytical_After_Testing + " " +
        Other + " " +
        Practice_Code + " " +
        Comments;
    }
}
```

Or make it a method...

```
public string AllData()
{
    return Occurrence_Date.ToString() + " " +
    Cup_Type + " " +
    Analytical_Testing_Phase + " " +
    Area + " " +
    Preanalytical_Before_Testing + " " +
    Postanalytical_After_Testing + " " +
    Other + " " +
    Practice_Code + " " +
    Comments;
}
```

Or override `ToString()` instead (which sort of makes sense in this context)

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Occurrence_Date.ToString() + " " +
    Cup_Type + " " +
    Analytical_Testing_Phase + " " +
    Area + " " +
    Preanalytical_Before_Testing + " " +
    Postanalytical_After_Testing + " " +
    Other + " " +
    Practice_Code + " " +
    Comments;
}
```

Comment: +1 good answer.  Just to clarify, `AllData` is not a method - it's a property.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Milimetic - It could be made into either at this point.  What the user has now is nothing since its not even valid code.

Answer (score 8):

Since you want *all* properties -  more succinct using reflection:

```
public string GetAllData()
{
    return string.Join(" ", typeof(LabOccurrenceForm).GetProperties().Select(x => x.GetValue(this, null)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public string AllData
{
    get
    {
        return Occurrence_Date.ToString() + " " +
        Cup_Type + " " +
        Analytical_Testing_Phase + " " +
        Area + " " +
        Preanalytical_Before_Testing + " " +
        Postanalytical_After_Testing + " " +
        Other + " " +
        Practice_Code + " " +
        Comments;
    }
}
```

You need to use return in a get within a class. It cannot exist by itself.

Comment: You need to use the Format Code Sample button in the answer editor so that your code shows up properly.

Answer (score 2):

for better performance, try:

```
public string AllData
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8}",
          Occurrence_Date.ToString(),
          Cup_Type,
          Analytical_Testing_Phase,
          Area,
          Preanalytical_Before_Testing,
          Postanalytical_After_Testing,
          Other,
          Practice_Code,
          Comments);
    }
}
```

or

```
public string AllData
{
    get
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendFormat({0} ", Occurrence_Date.ToString());
        sb.AppendFormat({0} ", Cup_Type);
        sb.AppendFormat({0} ", Analytical_Testing_Phase);
        sb.AppendFormat({0} ", Area);
        sb.AppendFormat({0} ", Preanalytical_Before_Testing);
        sb.AppendFormat({0} ", Postanalytical_After_Testing);
        sb.AppendFormat({0} ", Other);
        sb.AppendFormat({0} ", Practice_Code);
        sb.AppendFormat({0}", Comments);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make a method, you have to declare it as a method: `public string AllData()`  They way you've declared it, the compiler thinks you're trying to create a property, thus it wants you provide a `get{}` statement.

In either case, it's a minor change- to make a method, just add your parentheses at the end of the method name.  If you want a property, just add `get{` at the beginning and `}` at the end of your actual code and you'll be fine either way.

Usage isn't far different either: method: `string allData = lab.AllData()` or property `string allData = lab.AllData`

You might also consider just overriding .ToString() in your class.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the readonly field like this:

```
public string AllData
{
    get
    {
        return Occurrence_Date.ToString() + " " +
               Cup_Type + " " +
               Analytical_Testing_Phase + " " +
               Area + " " +
               Preanalytical_Before_Testing + " " +
               Postanalytical_After_Testing + " " +
               Other + " " +
               Practice_Code + " " +
               Comments;
    }
}
```